# Split the values and convert rows into columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have the following tables:

1. tblengineeringlookupcolumnmaster
2. tblengineeringlookupdetail

   elccolumnid   | elclookupcode | elccolumnname | elcisrequired

   ```
   1             |   64              |   FirstName |      1
   2             |   64              |   LastName  |      1
   ```

eldrecordId   | eldlookupcode    |eldlookupsequence |eldlookupvalue |   eldlookupvaluedescription

```
245     |     64        |    0         |   Red        |    Aravinth,Arumugam

246     |     64        |    1         |   Blue       |    Santhosh,Chandran

247     |     64        |    2         |   Green          |  Karthik,Balasubramanian
```

[image: SQL Tables]

I need the output as:

```
elcLookupCode | eldRecordId | FirstName | LastName 
-------------------------------------
64            | 245         | Aravinth  |  Arumugam
64            | 246         | Santhosh  |  Chandran    
64            | 247         | Karthik   |  Balasubramanian
```

Here the values in the `eldlookupvaluedescription` is `FirstName,LastName` of the `elcColumnName` in `tblengineeringlookupcolumnmaster` table. So I have to split according to the `elccolumnname` rows. If there are 3 rows in that table then I have to split the values of `eldlookupvaluedescription` accordingly. Need to handle the empty values also.

I have tried to splitting the values like.

```
 declare @sqlstr nvarchar(max); 
--Select the initial values
select @sqlstr = 'a,b,c,d,e,f';
--Replace the comma so the string becomes a','b','c','d','e','f
select @sqlstr = REPLACE(@sqlstr, ',', ''',''')
--Add select to the beginning and add leading and trailing ' around the select values
select @sqlstr = 'Select ''' + @sqlstr + ''''
--execute the dynamic sql of select 'a','b','c','d','e','f'
exec sp_executesql @sqlstr
```

How can I achieve this?

**Note**: Will be great if table variables are used instead of TempTables.

Comment: You are doing unholy things to a relation database, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/127172/264607.  You are never going to be able to query this data easily or efficiently.  If you can, redesign now, if you can't, run screaming.

Comment: Not a problem. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
        elcLookupCode INT
      , eldRecordId INT
      , txt VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (elcLookupCode, eldRecordId, txt)
VALUES 
    (64, 245, 'Aravinth,Arumugam'),
    (64, 246, 'Santhosh,Chandran'),    
    (64, 247, 'Karthik,Balasubramanian')

SELECT 
      t.elcLookupCode
    , t.eldRecordId
    , FirstName = txml.value('/t[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') 
    , LastName = txml.value('/t[2]', 'VARCHAR(20)') 
FROM @temp t
JOIN (
    SELECT 
          t2.eldRecordId
        , txml = CAST('<t>' + REPLACE(txt, ',', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
    FROM @temp t2
) t2 ON t.eldRecordId = t2.eldRecordId
```

**Output:**

```
elcLookupCode eldRecordId FirstName  LastName
------------- ----------- ---------- ----------
64            245         Aravinth   Arumugam
64            246         Santhosh   Chandran
64            247         Karthik    Balasubram
```

---

**Update**

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @tcol TABLE
(
      ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    , elclookupcode INT
    , elccolumnname VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @tcol (elclookupcode, elccolumnname)
VALUES 
    (64, 'FirstName'),
    (64, 'LastName')

DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
        elcLookupCode INT
      , eldRecordId INT
      , txt VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (elcLookupCode, eldRecordId, txt)
VALUES 
    (64, 245, 'Aravinth,Arumugam'),
    (64, 246, 'Santhosh,Chandran'),    
    (64, 247, 'Karthik,Balasubramanian')

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
          token = ', [' + d2.elccolumnname + '] = ''' + d.token + ''''
        , d.eldRecordId
    FROM (
        SELECT 
              token = t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)')
            , a.eldRecordId
            , a.elcLookupCode
            , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.eldRecordId ORDER BY a.eldRecordId)
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                  eldRecordId
                , elcLookupCode
                , txml = CAST('<t>' + REPLACE(txt, ',', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
            FROM @temp
        ) a
        CROSS APPLY txml.nodes('/t') t(c)
    ) d
    JOIN (
        SELECT 
              elclookupcode
            , elccolumnname
            , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY elclookupcode ORDER BY elclookupcode) 
        FROM @tcol 
    ) d2 ON d.elcLookupCode = d2.elclookupcode AND d2.rn = d.rn
)
SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
        SELECT CHAR(13) + 'UNION ALL SELECT [eldRecordId] = ' + CAST(eldRecordId AS VARCHAR(10)) + ', ' + 
           '[elcLookupCode] = ' + CAST(elcLookupCode AS VARCHAR(10)) + ', '+ STUFF((
        SELECT t2.token
        FROM cte t2
        WHERE t2.eldRecordId = t.eldRecordId
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
        FROM @temp t
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 11, '')

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

**Output:**

```
SELECT [eldRecordId] = 245, [elcLookupCode] = 64, [FirstName] = 'Aravinth', [LastName] = 'Arumugam'
UNION ALL SELECT [eldRecordId] = 246, [elcLookupCode] = 64, [FirstName] = 'Santhosh', [LastName] = 'Chandran'
UNION ALL SELECT [eldRecordId] = 247, [elcLookupCode] = 64, [FirstName] = 'Karthik', [LastName] = 'Balasubramanian'
```

**Results:**

```
eldRecordId elcLookupCode FirstName LastName
----------- ------------- --------- ---------------
245         64            Aravinth  Arumugam
246         64            Santhosh  Chandran
247         64            Karthik   Balasubramanian
```

Comment: Can u see the table image that I have posted?

Comment: Can u see the two tables that I have posted as an image. I have to join the two tables and get the output in which the column are to be taken from the first table(elccolumnname). Can u get me?

Comment: So can you use both the table names and make the output.?

Comment: Devart: I'm getting no rows if I query on the part where there are no values in the 2nd table. But I have defined the columns in the first table. So I should get the columns having null values. Correct? Why didn't it happen?

Comment: @Candy, can you update your question and add a small code sample for describe this situation.

Comment: I have posted as a new question. Please go thorough this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037231/dynamic-columns-not-getting-created-in-t-sql

Comment: Yes. But I need a some time to help you.