# How to represent a table with several one-to-many relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-5

I have a table, `A`, whose rows have a many-to-one relationship with several other tables. The rows in the other tables--`B`, `C`, `D`--each have many `A`s. Each `A` relates exclusively to another table. For example you never have an `A` that relates to both a `B` and `C`.

Currently, the `A` table is represented as a "flattened" sum-type where each row has a nullable `AId`, `BId`, `CId`, & `DId`. The "parent" of any given row in `A` is determined by which one of these FK's in non-null.

This has been working fine so far. However, I have several new features to be implemented down the road which will also have many `A`s.

My question is: is there a more extensible design than simply adding more columns to store FK's to these other tables?

Comment: It's hard to say something useful without knowing more about your usecase. At first glance I would say it seems silly to have this monster table `A`. Why not create a child table for each `B`, `C` and `D`? Yes, it's more tables, but it adds to clarity and performance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement polymorphic associations in an existing database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895806/how-to-implement-polymorphic-associations-in-an-existing-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a type of MUCK (massive unified code key)table, but only worse.

Instead of a table like this:

```
MUCK(aid, bid, cid, did, value1)
```

It would work better like this:

```
MUCK(table, id, value1)
```

The table is a,b,c, or d (or so on) and the id is the id within that table.

However, I really suggest you do some research on why MUCK and EAV tables can be a nightmare as you add requirements and features.

Here is a question I recently answered and a link to another that discusses why EAV (and even more, MUCK) is not always the best idea.

[How to store custom entity properties in a relational database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992520/how-to-store-custom-entity-properties-in-a-relational-database/29992885#29992885)