# SQL Nested Group within the Same Table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have data that looks something like this:

```
id      key         value
--------------------------------
1       country     us
1       state       nj
1       city        trenton
2       country     us
2       state       nj
2       city        springfield
3       country     us
3       state       nj
3       city        belmar
4       country     us
4       state       ny
4       city        new york
4       country     us
4       state       ny
4       city        white plains
4       country     canada
4       state       ontario
4       city        toronto
5       country     us
5       state       nj
5       city        trenton
```

I'm trying to write a SQL query to group by unique country, state, city

```
country     state       city
--------------------------------------
us          nj          trenton
us          nj          springfield
us          nj          belmar
us          ny          new york
us          ny          white plains
canada      ontario     toronto
```

I'm able to get DISTINCT country, state, and city, but I'm not sure how to join them together with the ID column.

Comment: There should be no need to 'group' them with the ID column, just `SELECT id, ...` and the rest of your query.

Comment: Looks like a key value pair table. Pivot the data first then your good; but note you need to know the number of keys you are pivoting... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126271/key-value-pairs-in-relational-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth stating for the record that this is a data mess and begs for "normalization". Having said that, you might try:

```sql
    SELECT cn.value as country, st.value as state, ct.value as city
    FROM table cn
    LEFT JOIN table st ON cn.id = st.id
    LEFT JOIN table st ON cn.id = ct.id
    WHERE cn.key = 'country'
    AND st.key = 'state'
    AND ct.key = 'city'
    ORDER BY cn.value , st.value , ct.value
```

Comment: thank you! yeah.. the data ain't pretty. it's the wordpress post meta table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation for this:

```
select t.id,
       max(case when t.key = 'country' then t.value end) as country,
       max(case when t.key = 'state' then t.value end) as state,
       max(case when t.key = 'city' then t.value end) as city
from t
group by id;
```

This has the advantage of keeping all `id`s, even when not all three values are populated.